# Making sure rsync only deletes files from source that also exist at the destination

Tags: rsync

Recently, I used `rsync` to copy a big directory with lots of sub-directories to an external HDD. Some files had too long file names and `rsync` couldn't copy them. After truncating the too long file names, I want those files to be copied as well. However, once I typed in a wrong `rsync` command and it copied into another directory, while `--remove-source-files` was one of the flags and consequently, some of the source directories were removed.

Now I want to have all the files at the destination to remain intact, without having anything in the destination removed/deleted, while having the new files at the source copied and the files that are common between to source and destination removed from the source.

Would this command do exactly what I want? Dry-run doesn't show what files would be removed:

`rsync -nrhtPsvv --stats --ignore-existing --remove-source-files /run/media/username/hdd1/DIR1 /run/media/username/external_hdd`

As far as I know, `--ignore-existing` wouldn't work with `--remove-source-files`.

Comment: If you do not want them removed why the flag to force them to be removed?

Comment: @David I want only the source files that are common between the source and destination to be removed.

Comment: Unless you have resolved the too long file names nothing will do what you want.

Comment: @Terrance I think you just skimmed through my post.

Comment: Oops, my bad.  I missed the one line.  I do however think that the `-u` or `--update` command might do what you want.